# Problem in two string comparison...!

Tags: iphone

LotteryAppDelegate *appDelegate = (LotteryAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Lotterycheck *check;

```
//NSString *trueval;
 BOOL found = NO;
    NSUInteger f;
for (f = 0; f < [appDelegate.books count]; f++) {



    check = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:f];

    checkthis = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", check.LotteryNumber];


    mystring =@"1234567"; //check.LotteryNumber;
    NSString *finel = checkthis;
    NSLog(@"Dynamic Value: %@",finel);
    NSLog(@"Static Value: %@",mystring);

    if ([mystring isEqualToString:finel]) {
        found = YES;
        [self showalert:finel];
        break;

    }
```

its not comapring the string " if([mystring isEqualToString:finel])" mystring is static value and finel is the value i am getting from the class lotterycheck..

Comment: You probably should have updated your previous question instead of asking the same one again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that an object belonging to appDelegate.books is of class Book, try the following code snippet.

```
BOOL found = NO;
NSString *mystring = @"1234567";

for (Book *book in appDelegate.books) {

     NSString *checkthis = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", book.LotteryNumber];

     if ([mystring isEqualToString checkthis]) {
        found = YES;
        [self showalert:checkthis];
        break;

    }
}
```